# Autolayout dynamic height table view cells render wrongly when text changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I have a a custom `UITableViewCell` using `Autolayout` and `iOS8 Dynamic Height`, containing two labels of different size. The upper label could be anywhere from **1 to 2 lines**, and the bottom label is always only 1 line.

In `:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` I set the text of the upper label to "Loading.." and call a method to retrieve the actual text from a server (or the cache) (which could be of any length). The second label is set to it's final text.

```
...
cell.title.text = @"Loading...";
cell.subtitle.text = source.name;

__weak NewsTableViewCell *weakCell = cell;
[[NewsManager sharedManager] getNewsForSource:source withBlock:^(NewsObject *object, NSError *error) {
    NewsTableViewCell *strongCell = weakCell;

    strongCell.title.text = object.articleHeadline;
}];
...
```

When the method returns and changes the text from "Loading..." to the actual text, one of three things happen:

1. Everything is rendered correctly.
2. The second label is removed and the first label is pinned to one line.
3. The first label is cut off at half width (this usually occurs after turning the phone sideways and back to portrait again).

I call `[self.tableView reloadData]` in `viewWillAppear:`, so if something is rendered wrongly, simply opening another view and returning to this fixes the problem. So does turning the phone to another side, and back to the original again.

Here's a picture explaining what happens (note: both cells should be like the second one):

[image]

Here's how I have set up the `UITableViewCell` in the `StoryBoard` with `AutoLayout`:

[image]
[image]

I have not changed any of the properties (like hugging and compression priority).

Could anyone guide me in the correct direction/ let me know what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT 1:** Here's a photo that shows the different `UILabel` `Frames` for (1) the correct layout (2) the wrong layout (3) the layout when the cell is waiting for it's final text (which causes the wrong layout to occur)

[image]

**EDIT 2:** Calling `[strongCell setNeedsLayout]` and `[strongCell layoutIfNeeded]` from the block doesn't solve my problem, but it causes this `AutoLayout` error to appear in the console. Could you help me debug this?

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you 
don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which 
you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or 
constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing 
NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the 
documentation for the UIView property 
translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 

(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1700927a0 UILabel:0x127d39c20'Horrifying moment lioness...'.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x127d2e510.topMargin>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170092930 V:[UILabel:0x127d39c20'Horrifying moment lioness...']-(8)-[UILabel:0x127d39dd0'Daily Mail Online']>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170092a70 UILabel:0x127d39dd0'Daily Mail Online'.bottom == UITableViewCellContentView:0x127d2e510.bottomMargin>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170092c00 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x127d2e510(0)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170092930 V:[UILabel:0x127d39c20'Horrifying moment lioness...']-(8)-[UILabel:0x127d39dd0'Daily Mail Online']>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Comment: You are approaching this incorrectly when the text loads. What you are currently doing is changing the text an assuming the layout will be fixed for you. You need to reload that cell when you get the new text. This will re layout the cell.

Comment: Los, store the downloaded text in an array so in cell for row you can check the array and set the title to "Loading..." If it isn't available or the text from the array if it is available. At the moment your approach is very ineffecient.

Comment: The reason I chose this approach is to have all the downloaded text centralized in one shared manager, instead of spread around to other controllers and arrays. The text should also update at certain times, and the perfect time to do that is when the cell rolls back into the view again (in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`) because that's a sign the user wants the most up-to-date-info.

Comment: I don't see how I can load the text for all these objects (could be hundreds) at the same time, store that in an array, and it would be more efficient than now. I don't load the text before it's necessary, I update it regularly without using a timer or when it's not useful to the user, and I don't keep around multiple copies. 

If you have any other suggestions as to how I can do this however, I'd be grateful. Keep in mind that loading all objects at startup is resource intensive and not useful to the user.

Comment: No, you misunderstand. Store the text maybe in a dictionary (with the indexpath as the key) but the first time you return the cell the text will not exist and you go to your service to get the text. But don't change the label, just store the text in the dictionary and call reload cell at indexpath. Then it will run this again and this time the text does exist and so it will put the downloaded text into the label. Because it has reloaded it will also fix the layout.

Comment: Don't load all the text. Just the text for the cells that become visible. But don't do this over and over, just download the text the first time and store it.

Comment: THis will stop the infinite loop at you mentioned against the other answer.

Comment: I have my laptop now. Give me a sec to write an answer.

Comment: Added my answer now. Hopefully that makes a bit more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the cell to be laid out again you need to `reload` the cell using the `reload` method.

You can achieve it this way...

First, create a mutable dictionary property to store the text for the cells...

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *textDictionary;
```

And initialise it somewhere.

Then in cell for row...

**Updated following comments**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ...

    cell.subtitle.text = source.name;

    // get the text from the dictionary
    NSString *titleText = self.textDictionary[source];

    if (titleText) {
        // second time through the text exists so just use it.
        cell.title.text = titleText;
    } else {
        // first time through the text is nil so set it to default and download it.
        cell.title.text = @"Loading...";

        // this just stops the download starting again before it has completed
        self.textDictionary[source] = @"Loading...";
    }

    // recheck the text and reload if it has changed
    [[NewsManager sharedManager] getNewsForSource:source withBlock:^(NewsObject *object, NSError *error) {
        NSString *oldText = self.textDictionary[source];
        NSString *newText = object.articleHeadline;

        // reload if the text has changed
        if (![oldText isEqualToString:newText]) {
            // store the text in the dictionary
            self.textDictionary[source] = newText;

            // reload the indexPath (will only trigger if the cell is visible)
            [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        }
    }];

    ....
}
```

The first time through this triggers the async fetching of the string. When it is completed it stores it locally and then reloads the row.

The second time through it will just get the locally stored string and use that without having to download again.

Comment: This is a clever solution, but it does cause some problems for me. Number one is that my `getNewsForSource:` not only gets the text from the cache if it's there, but also checks if it's outdated and should be reloaded. When I get the text from the `NSDictionary` this does not happen. Also, since the `NSDictionary` is arranged by the `indexPath`'s, when I remove one source and add another, they will appear to have the same text because they were at the same `indexPath`. Resetting the `textDictionary` in `viewWillAppear:` causes a number of bugs, so do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @Aleksander yeah, you can fetch the text each time and check if the current text. Is different. If it is different then store it and call reloadRows... That will still use this method but will set new text when it changes and re layout the cells.

Comment: @Aleksander as for storing the text. The best solution is to create an object model around the view. But you could get it working like this... Store the text in the textDictionary using the source as the key instead of the index oath. That way if you the source is removed then the text won't be loaded because it only loads the text from the source. `self.textDictionary[source] = theText;` and so on.

Comment: I was thinking about arranging by `source.name` instead of `indexPath`, however the problem still remains that it'll load from the dictionary next time instead of checking the `NewsManager` if it should be updated.

Comment: I really wanna do this properly (no half-assed solution), so what's the best way to achieve this? Basically every time a cell is brought into the view, I would like to get the news for the source at that index. If the news is in the cache, I'd like to check if it should be reloaded. If not, return the text from the cache. If it should be reloaded or isn't already in the cache, set the text as "Loading..." and replace it by the text when it has finished downloading it

Comment: @Aleksander it's only code. Change it if it doesn't work exactly how you want. I've edited now.

Comment: @Aleksander this is a good implementation. Nothing half assed about it.

Comment: @Aleksander No worries. Glad it works for you. Creating object models comes with practice and every one will be different for various reasons. This is a fairly lightweight way of storing the data for this particular problem. You may find a different way of storing it that allows you to not re download the text each time the cell is loaded but this will work for now :D

Comment: I'm actually not re downloading the text, simply checking a date at which the old data "expires" and should be reloaded. So there won't be any unnecessary network requests, but your point still stands. Just thought I'd clarify so you don't think I'm completely useless haha. Thanks again!

Comment: @Aleksander haha! Ah, that makes sense. I wasn't sure what the async request was doing but sounds like you've got it working quite well :-) and I didn't think you were useless anyway. Lol!

Comment: I have one more question, would you mind taking 5 minutes to chat with me here on StackOverflow?

Comment: @Aleksander sure. Invite me along :-) will help if I can :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79868/discussion-between-aleksander-and-fogmeister).

Answer (score 0):

> If you are using multi-line UILabels, don't forget that the preferredMaxLayoutWidth needs to be set correctly.

Try to set `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` of the upper label:

```
cell.title.preferredMaxLayoutWidth  = cell.title.bounds.size.width;
```

---

**EDIT:**

```
__weak NewsTableViewCell *weakCell = cell;
[[NewsManager sharedManager] getNewsForSource:source withBlock:^(NewsObject *object, NSError *error) {
    NewsTableViewCell *strongCell = weakCell;

    strongCell.title.text = object.articleHeadline;

    [strongCell setNeedsLayout];
    [strongCell layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

---

**EDIT AGAIN:**

I strongly suggest that you retrieve data in `viewDidLoad`. Table Views re-use cells. When a cell is scrolled offscreen it is added to a queue, and will be re-used for the next cell to be scrolled onscreen.

If you request data in `cellForRow` then you have to check the cell like this:

```
NSInteger row = indexPath.row;
[[NewsManager sharedManager] getNewsForSource:source withBlock:^(NewsObject *object, NSError *error) {

    // Update the datasource, e.g. caching the news in getNewsForSource:withBlock:

    UITableViewCell *dangerousCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0]];
    if (dangerousCell != nil) {
        NSString *articleHeadline = object.articleHeadline;
        if ([dangerousCell.title.text isEqualToString:articleHeadline]) {
            return;
        }
        textLabel.text = articleHeadline;
        [tableView reloadData];
    }
}];
```

Comment: I tried adding that line in both the passed block and the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, but it doesn't seem to make it better. Actually, now it seems to **always** cause the second label to disappear and the first one to be only one line despite text length, until you call `reloadData` again.

Comment: I tried calling `[strongCell layoutSubviews]` and `[strongCell layoutIfNeeded]` when changing the text, but this didn't work either. 

Shouldn't all of this work automatically really? I mean I've set the constraints correctly I believe, so I don't know why the textlabel doesn't grow to fit the content, why the second textlabel disappears, and why the cell doesn't grow to accommodate the larger text

Comment: The `block` of the `getNewsForSource` be called in the main thread?

Comment: `getNewsForSource:` checks to see if the object is in the cache. If it's in the cache, the `block()` is called from the `Main Thread`, if not it's called from a `Background Thread` which waits for a network conncetion. Does that matter? I know you can't make changes to the layout from a background thread, but changing the text works so I don't see why the layout doesn't render correctly. Also see the original post, I added another picture

Comment: I think that you have to update the cell's height while the request finished

Comment: How? I don't want to change the `frame.size` property manually, as this should be handled by `AutoLayout`

Comment: I tried the edits you suggested which doesn't make any changes to my problem, however it does cause an `AutoLayout` error to appear in the console. I will try to debug it myself, but I have added it to the original post hoping that maybe you can tell me what's wrong if I can't figure it out myself.

Comment: I mean that call `[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];` in the block

Comment: Wouldn't that cause an infinite loop? The article is loaded in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, so if I call `reloadRowsAtIndexPath:` inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, it'll just keep going?